# Turn an Abstract Syntax Tree from the ast module into a new python file.

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using the 'ast' module in python to create a Abstract Syntax Tree. I want to be able to edit the AST(I am editing with 'ast.NodeTransformer') and then take that new tree and write it to a new python file. According to the website "http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html" there is no way to do this without using a third party package.    Is this true, or can I write a AST to a new python file using the 'ast' module?    If so, how do I do it? It seems like 'ast' would support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a third party module called [`codegen.py`](http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/file/b2aea937f5bb/ast/codegen.py), but it itself just uses the bulitin AST machinery under the hood its very simple. From there you can use the builtin `ast.NodeTransformer` machinery to transform the AST nodes.

```
import ast
import codegen

class Visitor(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        return ast.Num(42)

x = Visitor()
t = ast.parse('x + y + z + 3')
out = x.visit(t)
print codegen.to_source(out)
# x + y + z + 42
```